# Отправка документа на стену docs.save vk api

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

При выполнении данного кода возникает ошибка в последней строке.

```
 $save = vk('docs.save', [
            'group_id' => $group_id,
            'file' => $upload->file,
            'v' => '5.92'
        ])->response[0];
```

что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

как выяснилось код должен быть таким

```
 $save = vk('docs.save', [
            'group_id' => $group_id,
            'file' => $upload->file,
            'v' => '5.92'
        ]);
```